# How to read incoming sms messages without sending an auto-response

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I want to read an incoming message from Twilio. I have set up the tunneling with ngrok as advised on their website.

I am able to send the message using the following

**SendMessage.java**

```
Twilio.init(SendAndReceiveController.ACCOUNT_SID, SendAndReceiveController.AUTH_TOKEN);
    Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(receiver),
            new PhoneNumber(sender),smsContent).create();
```

I have tried 4 different methods to do a receive/read.

**ReceiveMessage.java**

```
MessageFetcher mf = new MessageFetcher("SM2ccd0dc43cea07bcc3f522b3e571eb79");
    System.out.println("message is " + mf.fetch().getBody());   <-- Method 1

    Body body = new Body("Something here");                     <-- Method 2
    Message message = new Message.Builder().action("/receive-sms")
            .method(Method.POST).body(body).build();
    MessagingResponse response = new MessagingResponse.Builder().message(message).build();

    ResourceSet<Message> messages = Message.reader().read();    <-- Method 3

    for(Message message : messages){
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    try {
        System.out.println(response.toXml());
    } catch (TwiMLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    post("/receive-sms", (req, res)-> {                         <-- Method 4
        // This gets the message content
        System.out.println(req.queryParams("Body"));            
        // GOT CONTENT
        // Must parse the format and get the content value
        // Must be able to get the latest message

        Message sms = new Message.Builder()
                .body(new Body(""))
                .build();

        MessagingResponse twiml = new MessagingResponse.Builder()
                .message(sms)
                .build();

        return twiml.toXml();
    });
```

I am currently using method 4. While it works, I am forced to send a message back since it is a post [This is using the sparkjava library]. I emailed back and forth with Twilio's technical help, and they kept recommending it to me to use the callback function in Twilio's REST api. I believe that the post method I have used is a callback function.

Is there any way for me to read in the user's latest message without sending a response? If so, could you please explain a little in code how to do so? I am having difficulty in understanding how to translate it to Java since most of the code on their website appears to be in HTML.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The way to retrieve messages would be to use the ResourceSet<Message> . However, eclipse is throwing an error of Bound Mismatch: The type Message is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends resource> of the type ResourceSet<E>. I have tried extending Message as well. It didn't work (unless I didn't extend it correctly).

Comment: Figured out the problem. The Message in method 3 and method 4 were from different imports - com.twilio.twiml.Message and com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message. They were clashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are right to be using method 4. You are receiving the incoming message as a POST request to your `/receive-sms` endpoint.

But, you don't want to reply! That's nice and easy thankfully. Instead of building up a `MessagingResponse` with a `Message` you can just leave it empty.

```
post("/receive-sms", (req, res)-> {                         <-- Method 4
    // This gets the message content
    System.out.println(req.queryParams("Body"));            
    // GOT CONTENT
    // Must parse the format and get the content value
    // Must be able to get the latest message

    // do something with the content

    MessagingResponse twiml = new MessagingResponse.Builder().build();
    return twiml.toXml();
});
```

This will produce the following TwiML as a result:

```
<Response />
```

and will not send a message in reply.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help! I didn't realize that I could exclude the body from the MessagingResponse to create a non-response.